# Invoking WebApi's another action in another controller via reflection ?

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-web-api

We have many services in our system. ( integrating with a mobile company)

So, (for example) we have  :

```
Action1 in Controller1
Action2 in Controller1
...

Action4 in Controller4
Action5 in Controller4
...
```

Currently, the mobile company calls each action with a *single* request.

But recently they told us , "*can we send you a list of Actions to invoke ? instead of running single action manually each time... ?*"

So I tried reflection:

`ServicesController` :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage AAA( )
    {
        Type type = typeof(UsersController);

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Test2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var t=  method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { "royi" });

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, t);
    }
```

And :

`UseresController :`

```
 [HttpGet]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public HttpResponseMessage Test2( string ggg)
 { 
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "hello"+ggg);
 }
```

When I run via fiddler :

`http://es.com/api/services/aaa` ( GET)

It does work , but (obviously) the `Request` on the other side is null :

[image]

**Question**

How can I make `Test2` run as expected ? am I on the right direction of solving this ? or does webApi has built in mechanism for this sort of thing ?

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Querying multiple endpoints via a single endpoint isn't the best RESTful practice to be using. If you simply want to batch those actions together, why not expose a new endpoint to the user and internally receive these actions via dependency injection?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `AAA` is the single endopoint you've mentioned. so they will send me a JSON which contains all actions to invoke ( including params) , and I need to run and aggregate the results. **the whole point** here is that I won't need to write code when they want a new aggregation.

Comment: That means the caller knows how your actions are laid out in your `Controller`. I'm not sure thats such a good idea. The caller needs to describe to you what he needs, and you need to map those requests internally to an action.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No. that means that he can invoke whatever he wants from the services I exposed him. just like he used to as a single requests. but now , instead of single , he sends multiple ( as a json). the JSON looks like ( sort of) :  http://i.imgur.com/TM2H2S9.png

Comment: How about this: Create a mapping between the request key the user sends you (which can be your endpoint address or whatever) to an `Action`. Inject all those actions to your `AggregatedController`, and then simply extract the proper actions at runtime and invoke them with the proper parameters.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sorry , I don't understand your solution can you pls supply 3 lines of psuedo code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67901/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-royi-namir).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You better use the `ActionInvoker` to do that:

```
public HttpResponseMessage AAA()
{
    var ctrlDesc = new HttpControllerDescriptor(this.Configuration, "UsersController", typeof(UsersController));
    var actionDesc = new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(ctrlDesc, typeof(UsersController).GetMethod("Test2"));
    var ctrlCtx = new HttpControllerContext(this.Configuration, this.Request.GetRouteData(), this.Request);

    var apiCtrl = ctrlDesc.CreateController(this.Request) as ApiController;

    apiCtrl.Request = this.Request;
    apiCtrl.Configuration = this.Configuration;
    apiCtrl.ControllerContext = ctrlCtx;

    ctrlCtx.Controller = apiCtrl;
    ctrlCtx.ControllerDescriptor = ctrlDesc;
    ctrlCtx.Request = this.Request;
    ctrlCtx.RouteData = this.Request.GetRouteData();

    var actionContext = new HttpActionContext(ctrlCtx, actionDesc);
    actionContext.ActionArguments.Add("ggg", "royi");

    var invoker = this.Configuration.Services.GetActionInvoker();

    return invoker.InvokeActionAsync(actionContext, CancellationToken.None).Result;
}
```

Comment: I Just tried it and `Request` in `Test2()` method is not null and working as expected.

Comment: I didn't notice that `Test2` is in a different controller. Will update soon.

Comment: It's a shame I can't vote twice :-) Thank you Haim . ( working )